# Arduino UNO instantly disconnects after connection

Tags: node.js, arduino, node-serialport

I've been struggling getting node.js (Javascript) code that works on a Windows machine (Windows 8), but not on a Macintosh (OS X Snow Leopard). The code here is the Macintosh code, which has some code modified:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
var port = new SerialPort("/dev/tty.usbmodem3d11", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    flowControl: false
});

port.on('open',function() {
  console.log('Port open');
});

port.on('close',function() {
    console.log('Port closed');
});

port.on('data', onData);
```

Here is the output:

```
Port open
Port closed
```

The port seems to close instantly after opening. I'm not exactly sure why. Any clues? (I know that DTR/DSR issues could be behind it, but I'm not sure how to fix those.)